# What is the workaround in Hibernate to replace absent interface support?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's suppose we have the following tables:

```
USER (user_id)
USER_OWNER (own_id, user_id, type, emp_id, std_id)
EMPLOYEE (emp_id)
STUDENT (std_id)
```

So, we have a user owner that can be either an employee or a student. We have table USER_OWNER that has FK to EMPLOYEE and STUDENT to provide data integrity.

As I found out neither JPA nor Hibernate supports interfaces. So, what is the best way to solve this problem without inheritance in Hibernate (I can't use inheritance as I need a generic solution for different classes that are not inherited, for example, car, book, table etc)? How to make these relations?

As I understand

```
@Entity
class User {
   
    private ?UserOwner? owner;
}


@Entity
class Employee {
....
}

@Entity
class Student {
...
}
```

But what about UserOwner?

Comment: Imagine that interfaces are supported. What mapping do you want to have?

Comment: @SternK I've edited the question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: How would you create the SQL statements with such a generic solution?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Sorry, didn't understand the question. Firstly I create tables USER, EMPLOYEE, STUDENT and at the end USER_OWNER with 3 FK. Student and Employee FK can be null.

Comment: My question is how would access the data if the solution is generic and you cannot use inheritance

Comment: @SimonMartinelli The SQL tables structure fits my needs very well. So, SQL code is what I need. Now I need to find a suitable solution to use this SQL code with Hibernate.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli A generic problem I am trying to solve is in creating CRUD application that allows to insert different documents in some fields of another documents. I can't use inheritance because there is no inheritance between these documents.

Comment: If you cannot use inheritance to make UserOwner the base class then there is no solution